# How to switch from simple activity to drawer activity?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to know how to switch from a simple activity to drawer activity. I read that there are 2 ways to do it.

The first is `Intent i =new Intent("com.example.signin");`

the second is `Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,signin.class);`

I tried both. But in the 1st case, my layout which contains toolbar, drawer and the button inside is appearing perfect. But buttons functionality is not working. in 2nd case, buttons functionality is working but layout is disturbed.

Can anyone tell me solution for this problem?I'm using Android Studio.
here is my code:

MainActivity

```
package com.example.asus1.tlogin;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button signInBtn;
    private Button signUpBtn;
    private Button submit;
    private EditText mUsername, mPassword;
    private Layout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signInBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signUpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        //String userName = mUsername.getText().toString();
        // String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

        signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.asus1.tlogin.SignUpActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter username..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mPassword.setText("");
                    mUsername.setText("");
                } else if (mPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mPassword.setText("");
                    mUsername.setText("");
                } else if (mUsername.getText().toString().equals("gaurav") && mPassword.getText().toString().equals("gaurav")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContentDrawer.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    setContentView(R.layout.content_drawer);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong username or password..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPassword.setText("");
                    mUsername.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ContentDrawer.java:

```
package com.example.asus1.tlogin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ContentDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button createBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_drawer);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.draw);

        createBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createBtn);
        createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CreateGroup.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ContentDrawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.asus1.tlogin.DrawerActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:text="Create your personal profile"
        android:background="#d31313"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/createBtn"
        android:clickable="false" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#f29494"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Join group"
            android:id="@+id/joinGroup"
            android:background="#984848"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Setup a group"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="#4e7db2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:text="Setup an eventk"
        android:id="@+id/eventBtn"
        android:background="#e7ed21"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="#8b9ddb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:com.facebook.widget.LoginButtonandroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.asus1.tlogin.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/roomates1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/signup"
                android:background="#0000"
                android:text="SIGN UP"
                android:textAlignment="gravity" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/signin"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/signup"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/signup"
                android:background="#0000"
                android:text="             SIGN IN"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="#fefefe"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="272dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: plz share code and screenshot of your app....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> layout is disturbed

I'm assuming what you mean by that is that you are completely replacing the layout of the MainActivity?

That is fixable by just not doing so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContentDrawer.class);
startActivity(intent);

// Remove this line
/* setContentView(R.layout.content_drawer); */
```

Other than that, it seems you should be able to start the other Activity just fine.